# java order arraylist string[] by number

Tags: java, sorting, collections, types

i have an array list of type String[]. i want to order it by String[0] as a int. i have this:

```
Collections.sort(listitems, new Comparator<String[]>() {
 @Override
 public int compare(String[] lhs, String[] rhs) {
  return lhs[0].compareToIgnoreCase(rhs[0]);
 }
});
```

but this order like this:
10
11
12
2
20
21
3
4
5
i have tried to convert the `lhs[0]` and `rhs[0]` to `int`, but the `int` type doesn't have any kind of compare and i'm not sure what type of `int` i need to return

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The result from `compare` is meant to be:

- Negative if the first argument is logically "less than" the second
- Positive if the first argument is logically "more than" the second
- Zero if the first argument is logically equal to the second

So if you're *sure* that the first string of each array is parsable as an integer, I'd use:

```
@Override
public int compare(String[] lhs, String[] rhs) {
    int leftInt = Integer.parseInt(lhs[0]);
    int rightInt = Integer.parseInt(rhs[0]);
    return leftInt < rightInt ? -1
        : leftInt > rightInt ? 1
        : 0;
}
```

Java 1.7 has the helpful `Integer.compare` method, but I assume that won't be available to you. You could use `Integer.compareTo` but that may create more garbage than you really want on a mobile device...

Note that this will work even when `leftInt` and `rightInt` are very large, or possibly negative - the solution of just subtracting one value from another assumes that the subtraction won't overflow.

Comment: Integer.parseInt(lhs); - you try to parse an array - it will not work

Comment: +1 And note that one also has to be sure each array is non-empty.

Comment: int leftInt = Integer.parseInt(lhs[0]);
    int rightInt = Integer.parseInt(rhs[0]);

Comment: @PaulBellora: Oh yes, all kinds of things could go wrong in terms of a value being null, the array being empty, or it not being a valid integer.

Answer (score 2):

I think this should do the work for you, if we assume that the contents of the arrays are string representations of integers:

```
Collections.sort(listitems, new Comparator<String[]>() {
 @Override
 public int compare(String[] lhs, String[] rhs) {
  return Integer.valueOf(lhs[0]).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(rhs[0]));
 }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You comparison is based on the alphabetical ordering of the number. To compare them numerically:

```
Integer.parseInt(lhs[0]) - Integer.parseInt(rhs[0]);
```

Comment: It won't work if you end up with overflow. For example if lhs[0] is "-2147483648" and rhs[0] is "1".

Answer (score 0):

You can try Integer.parseInt(1hs[0])-Integer.parseInt(rhs[0]);

or

int    compareTo(Integer anotherInteger)  sytnax

or

decode(String nm)